# Making a first-class Function with arguments in Python

Tags: python, first-class-functions

My issue is simple: I want to make a first-class function in python that has some arguments in it.
But the problem is that to assign it, you need to call it, wich can be problematic

```
def print_double(num):
    print(num*2)
a = print_double(4)
```

I don't want to call it when I assign it, I would like to call it when I need it. Something like:

```
a()
>>> 8
```

Is there any way I can do it?

Comment: Can you clarify your question, please? What a problem to store your print_double() at a separate module and do "module import print_double as a" ?

Comment: All Python functions are first-class. That's the wrong terminology. It looks like you want to write a function that returns another function (a [closure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming))), or maybe you're actually looking for a [partial](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#partial-objects) -- it's not totally clear.

Comment: Better link: [`partial`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As written, your code would throw an error - NoneType is not callable.

To do what you've shown, you'd need to curry the function

```
def print_double(num):
    def inner():
       print(num*2)
    return inner 

a = print_double(4)
a()  # 8
```